# Play WS exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Tags: java, scala, ssl, playframework

I'm using Play Framework (version 2.3.10) and I'm having an issue while using the WS module. This problem arises when trying to fetch some HTTPS sites (like https://insightware.com (disclaimer: that's my company site)).

Enabling debug on WS I get the following output:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Using SSLEngineImpl.
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1445087486 bytes = { 146, 237, 255, 111, 129, 37, 142, 110, 194, 251, 49, 61, 192, 92, 156, 255, 245, 197, 248, 149, 114, 80, 29, 202, 68, 66, 250, 243 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 237
0000: 01 00 00 E9 03 03 56 22   49 FE 92 ED FF 6F 81 25  ......V"I....o.%
0010: 8E 6E C2 FB 31 3D C0 5C   9C FF F5 C5 F8 95 72 50  .n..1=.\......rP
0020: 1D CA 44 42 FA F3 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  ..DB....d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 5C 00 0A 00 34 00 32 00   17 00 01 00 03 00 13 00  \...4.2.........
00A0: 15 00 06 00 07 00 09 00   0A 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00  ................
00B0: 19 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00   10 00 11 00 02 00 12 00  ................
00C0: 04 00 05 00 14 00 08 00   16 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00  ................
00D0: 0D 00 1A 00 18 06 03 06   01 05 03 05 01 04 03 04  ................
00E0: 01 03 03 03 01 02 03 02   01 02 02 01 01           .............
New I/O worker #1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 237
[Raw write]: length = 242
0000: 16 03 03 00 ED 01 00 00   E9 03 03 56 22 49 FE 92  ...........V"I..
0010: ED FF 6F 81 25 8E 6E C2   FB 31 3D C0 5C 9C FF F5  ..o.%.n..1=.\...
0020: C5 F8 95 72 50 1D CA 44   42 FA F3 00 00 64 C0 24  ...rP..DB....d.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 5C 00 0A   00 34 00 32 00 17 00 01  .....\...4.2....
00A0: 00 03 00 13 00 15 00 06   00 07 00 09 00 0A 00 18  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00 0D   00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00 11  ................
00C0: 00 02 00 12 00 04 00 05   00 14 00 08 00 16 00 0B  ................
00D0: 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00 1A   00 18 06 03 06 01 05 03  ................
00E0: 05 01 04 03 04 01 03 03   03 01 02 03 02 01 02 02  ................
00F0: 01 01                                              ..
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 50                                              .P
New I/O worker #1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
New I/O worker #1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, internal_error
New I/O worker #1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
New I/O worker #1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
New I/O worker #1, called closeOutbound()
New I/O worker #1, closeOutboundInternal()
New I/O worker #1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
New I/O worker #1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
New I/O worker #1, called closeInbound()
New I/O worker #1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 01 00                               .......
New I/O worker #1, called closeOutbound()
New I/O worker #1, closeOutboundInternal()
```

and thus the exception:

```
[info]   Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: internal_error to https://insightware.com/
[info]   at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:103)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:431)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:417)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:384)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1578)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1380)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:918)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
[info]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[info]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[info]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[info]   Cause: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
[info]   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
[info]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
[info]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
[info]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
[info]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
[info]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
[info]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
[info]   at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1284)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:918)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
[info]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[info]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[info]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Additional information:

- I'm running Oracle Java version `1.8.0_60`. Downgrading to Java 7 didn't solve the problem.
- Installed Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files. Previous unavailable cipher suites warnings disappeared but problem is still there.
- I even tried using the "ws.acceptAllCertificates" WS configuration option, just for the sake of it, but the problem persisted.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the developper of [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) (AHC), the HTTP client Play's WS decorates.

Play 2.3 uses AHC 1.8 that suffered from several HTTPS issues because we were targeting JDK6 and the proper features are only available since JDK7.

You have to upgrade to Play 2.4, so you can use AHC 1.9. You can't just upgrade AHC as they are not compatible. And no, there's no workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally bit the bullet and updated from 2.3.10 to 2.4.